# What do you call people who are searching for home?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with a title for my short story and the story is about people who are searching for home (whether it be a person or a place). What would be a good one word for that?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. Could you please provide a little of what your basic research showed you? Also, the SWR tag requires a sample sentence demonstrating usage of the target language.

Comment: It would help if you could specify whether you're looking for a word for the people, eg wanderers, searchers, or for the home? Or the act of looking?

Comment: There is a self-explanatory word: [_homeseeker_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homeseeker). A more spiritual word would be _pilgrim_ but it is  usually used in religious context.

Comment: _Lost_ would be one word…

Comment: *Homeless* could be one too

Comment: Please provide a little more information as Cascabel requests.

Comment: There's a chance hobo is an abbreviated form of homeward bound.

Answer (score 0):

Or try something more metaphorical, like Odysseus (Greek) or Ulysses (Latin version) 
Or the Ancient Greek term 'nostos' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostos

Answer (score 0):

My first impulse would be to call them "seekers".